# How do I remove text format information from the bottom of my text areas

Tags: 7, entities, input-formats

I have a content type which all of my users can create instances of.  The last text area has a section listing the particulars of the text format.  I would like to disable this area so that the test format does not explain itself, and all the user sees is a text area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Simplify module](https://drupal.org/project/simplify) for this.

It describes itself as follows:

*Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more user-friendly experience to content editors.*